# Декодирование UART Спомощью python

Tags: python, uart

Есть такая задача:
Прочитайте файл с записью сигнала передаваемого по UART без проверки на четность. Скорость передачи данных 9600 бод. Частота дискретизации сигнала 240кГц. Передача начинается с младшего бита. Напишите программу для приема сообщения, учитывая что при передаче символов, состоящих из 8 бит, использовалась кодировка ASCII. Выведите:

1. на первой строке - первый символ;
2. на второй строке - второй символ;
3. на третьей строке - третий символ;
4. на четвертой строке - номер отсчета, с которого начинается передача первого символа;
5. на пятой строке - продолжительность передачи одного бита, выраженную в количестве отсчетов.

Не помнимаю как правильно решить, получаю то не понятные символы то пустые строки то нули, в общем не подступается, был бы благодарен за решение

[image: Файл с данными выглядит вот так(начало)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начни с того что нарисуй график этого ряда.

Найди стартовый бит. Это переход от 1 к 0.

```
    for I in range(start, len(data)):
        if I<2:
            start = I
            break
```

От этого момента отмеряешь `240000/9600*1.5` и считываешь значения через каждые `240000/9600*1` строк.

```
B=0
for I  in range(8):
    v=1 if int(data[start+240000/9600*1.5+I])>2 else 0
    B|=v<<I
```